# How do I delete one list variable after calling it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
States = 'alabama', 'alaska', 'arizona', 'arkansas'.....
randomState = random.randint(1, 50)
print(States[randomState])
```

I made a script that randomly picks a state out of 50, it works but I want to also delete the state that it called that it was it doesn't repeat using the same variable the next iteration that it is called.

Comment: That's a `tuple` which are inmutable, use a `list` so you can remove an item

Comment: wrap `States` in brackets (so it is a list and mutable) and then `del States[randomState]`

Comment: note that after you removed an element from the list, calling another element at a random index from `random.randint(1, 50)` might fail due to an `IndexError` since you no longer have 50 elements.

Comment: and while you're at it, make sure you don't delete list elements while you're looping over the list, should that be your next step.... (don't change the thing you're looping over)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to remove an element at known index in a list you can use the pop function.

> [Python Data Structures](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)
>
> list.pop([i])
> Remove the item at the given position in the list, and
> return it. If no index is specified, a.pop() removes and returns the
> last item in the list. (The square brackets around the i in the method
> signature denote that the parameter is optional, not that you should
> type square brackets at that position. You will see this notation
> frequently in the Python Library Reference.)

Please note, if you will try to pop an "out of range" index a "IndexError" will be raise.

Regarding this:

> "I want to also delete the state that it called that it was it doesn't repeat using the >same variable the next iteration"

The following code will print all the states randomly until all the states in the list will be printed without removing the state from the original list permanently (it will mix up the original order).

```
import random

states = ['alabama', 'alaska', 'arizona', 'arkansas']
already_printed_count = 0

while already_printed_count < len(states):
    random_state = states.pop(random.randint(0, len(states) - already_printed_count - 1))
    already_printed_count += 1
    states.append(random_state)
    print(random_state)
```

output:

```
alaska
arkansas
alabama
arizona
>>> states
['alaska', 'arkansas', 'alabama', 'arizona']
```

Answer (score 4):

Here we are

```
import random

States = ['alabama', 'alaska', 'arizona', 'arkansas']
randomState = random.randint(0, len(States) - 1)
print(States.pop(randomState))
```

### Example for multiple calls

```
import random

States = ['alabama', 'alaska', 'arizona', 'arkansas']

while States:
    randomState = random.randint(0, len(States) - 1)
    print('Removed random state: {}'.format(States.pop(randomState)))
```

outputs

```
python test.py
Removed random state: alaska
Removed random state: alabama
Removed random state: arizona
Removed random state: arkansas
```